# Why isn't copy operation implemented in kernel?

Tags: windows, file, api, filesystems, kernel

It's my understanding that most file IO operations are implemented in the kernel, such as CRUD, move or remove. However file copy is not implemented as a kernel level API.

In order to detect a file copy in the kernel one will need to use heuristics approach ([discussion on this approach](https://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=154815)), e.g. as detect file reads, file creates and file writes from the same user with the same file name, but different paths.

Why copy is a user land operation?

Comment: 99.9% of the work is in fact done by ring 0 code. The file system cache, the file system driver and the disk driver do the real work. Making the remaining 0.1% kernel code just isn't useful, the kernel itself never copies files.  And users do like a pretty userland progress dialog and a choice when there a copy conflicts.

Comment: Because file copy is not an atomic operation. It's a "read + write" operation with data modifications possible in between. Even if copy were a separate operation, you would complain that you can't track the file being put in ZIP or encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

First, because caring about whether or not two different files have the same content, where one file's content is copied directly from the other, is a user-space concern that has no logical reason to exist inside a kernel.

At best.

Bytes are bytes.

Second, how would the kernel distinguish copying a file between what are just two different file descriptors?  [See the man page for `sendfile()`.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html)  Why should the kernel track if the calling user called `sendfile()` to send the contents of a file to a TCP socket to who-knows-where or to another file?

Third, even if the kernel tracked copying a file, what on God's good Earth would it **do** with such data?

If you care about such file copy events, set up auditing.

Comment: Auditing is useless - it won't detect file copying as well.

Comment: I ask this question specifically, because auditing does not detect file copy. You can get a few audit events, which you can assemble into a file copy, however this is heuristics, and it can get wrong.